# Является ли "дремучий" эпитетом?

Tags: стилистика, литературоведение

Насколько я знаю, эпитет должен выражаться словом, употребленном не в своем обычном значении. В словосочетании *дремучий лес* тропов нет, т. к. *дремучий* — значит "густой, темный (о лесе)". Верно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В фольклоре есть так называемые **постоянные эпитеты**, закрепленные традицией: чисто поле, красна девица, добрый молодец, добрый конь.

Поэтому всё зависит от текста: в сказках герои попадают обязательно  **в дремучий лес** (эпитет), а обычный густой лес — это просто дремучий (определение).

Answer (score 1):

> В словосочетании дремучий лес тропов нет, т. к. дремучий — значит
>   "густой, темный (о лесе)". Верно ли это?

Да, это действительно так. Дремучий (лес) — это не эпитет, это объективная оценка признака существительного "лес". Нельзя сказать: хорошо это или плохо, для кого-то хорошо, для кого-то — нет.

А вот дремучий (человек) — это эпитет, это субъективная оценка автора, и это, очевидно, плохо.